# How do you query Active record with enums

Tags: activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am trying this query and it is not working:

```
OrderFulfillment.where(shopper_id: shopper.id, fulfillment_status:  [:fulfillment_requested_assignment, :fulfillment_assigned, :fulfillment_shopping])
```

I am not sure why but I am unable to get querying using enums to work

Comment: What errors are you getting? What does the server log say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OrderFulfillment.where(shopper_id: shopper.id, 
                       fulfillment_status: OrderFulfillment
                         .fulfillment_statuses
                           .values_at([:fulfillment_requested_assignment,
                                       :fulfillment_assigned,
                                       :fulfillment_shopping]))
```

Rails isn't smart enough to know that you are passing keys and not values, so when you were passing the statuses straight like that it was looking for the wrong values (it changed them to `null` because it didn't understand). The enums are physically stored as integers, so that's what you actually need to use in the query. Therefore, you can use the Rails-provided `fulfillment_statuses` method to grab a hash of the key/value pairs of the enum, and then the `values_at` method of the hash to get the values for the array of keys you pass in.